# How can I simulate a click on Highchart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, jestjs

This is my DashboardPage component:

```js
export const DashboardPage = (props) => {

    const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);

    const { index } = props;

    let navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (mounted === false) {
            setMounted(true);
            index();
        }
    }, [mounted, index]);

    const optionNUsersPerCompany = {
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Utenti per azienda'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        accessibility: {
            point: {
                valueSuffix: '%'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
                },
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Utenti',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: getDataUsersPerCompany(props.items),
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: (e) => {
                        console.log(e);
                        props.setCompanyIdInUsersStore(e.target.point.idCompany);
                        return navigate(PATH_USERS);
                    }
                }
            }
        }]
    }

    return (
        <Chart options={optionNUsersPerCompany} />
    )
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {

    return {
        index: () => dispatch(statsActions.index()),
        setCompanyIdInUsersStore: (id) => dispatch(companiesActions.setCompanyIdInUsersStore(id)),
    };
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {

    return {
        items: state.stats.items,
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DashboardPage);
```

And this is the simple Highchart Component:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';

export default React.memo(function Chart(props) {

    const [currentOptions, setCurrentOptions] = useState({});

    /**
     * Questo controllo serve a non re-draware per due volte di seguito i containers
     */
    if (JSON.stringify(props.options) !== JSON.stringify(currentOptions)) {
        setCurrentOptions(props.options);
    }

    return (
        <HighchartsReact
            highcharts={Highcharts}
            options={currentOptions}
            immutable={true}
        />
    );
});
```

I want to test the click on plotOptions with Jest in React Highcharts. This is the resulting HTML page from Jest:

```html
  <div>
    <div
      data-highcharts-chart="1"
      style="overflow: hidden;"
    >
      <div
        class="highcharts-container "
        dir="ltr"
        id="highcharts-r3a94y8-149"
        style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 600px; height: 400px; text-align: left; line-height: normal; z-index: 0; user-select: none; outline: none;"
      >
        <svg
          class="highcharts-root"
          height="400"
          style="font-family: \"Lucida Grande\", \"Lucida Sans Unicode\", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;"
          version="1.1"
          viewBox="0 0 600 400"
          width="600"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
          <desc>
            Created with Highcharts 10.1.0
          </desc>
          <defs>
            <clippath
              id="highcharts-r3a94y8-151-"
            >
              <rect
                fill="none"
                height="375"
                width="580"
                x="0"
                y="0"
              />
            </clippath>
          </defs>
          <rect
            class="highcharts-background"
            fill="#ffffff"
            height="400"
            rx="0"
            ry="0"
            width="600"
            x="0"
            y="0"
          />
          <rect
            class="highcharts-plot-background"
            fill="none"
            height="375"
            width="580"
            x="10"
            y="10"
          />
          <rect
            class="highcharts-plot-border"
            data-z-index="1"
            fill="none"
            height="375"
            width="580"
            x="10"
            y="10"
          />
          <g
            class="highcharts-series-group"
            data-z-index="3"
          >
            <g
              class="highcharts-series highcharts-series-0 highcharts-pie-series highcharts-tracker"
              data-z-index="0.1"
              opacity="1"
              style="cursor: pointer;"
              transform="translate(10,10) scale(1 1)"
            >
              <path
                class="highcharts-point highcharts-color-0"
                d="M 290 175 A 0 0 0 0 1 290 175 L 290 175 A 0 0 0 0 0 290 175 Z"
                fill="#7cb5ec"
                opacity="1"
                stroke="#ffffff"
                stroke-linejoin="round"
                stroke-width="1"
                transform="translate(0,0)"
              />
            </g>
            <g
              class="highcharts-markers highcharts-series-0 highcharts-pie-series"
              data-z-index="0.1"
              opacity="1"
              transform="translate(10,10) scale(1 1)"
            />
          </g>
          <text
            class="highcharts-title"
            data-z-index="4"
            style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-size: 18px; fill: #333333;"
            text-anchor="middle"
            x="300"
            y="24"
          >
            Utenti per azienda
          </text>
          <text
            class="highcharts-subtitle"
            data-z-index="4"
            style="color: rgb(102, 102, 102); fill: #666666;"
            text-anchor="middle"
            x="300"
            y="10"
          />
          <text
            class="highcharts-caption"
            data-z-index="4"
            style="color: rgb(102, 102, 102); fill: #666666;"
            text-anchor="start"
            x="10"
            y="397"
          />
          <g
            class="highcharts-data-labels highcharts-series-0 highcharts-pie-series highcharts-tracker"
            data-z-index="6"
            opacity="0"
            style="cursor: pointer;"
            transform="translate(10,10) scale(1 1)"
          >
            <path
              class="highcharts-data-label-connector highcharts-color-0"
              d="M 295 370 C 290 370 290 352 290 346 L 290 340"
              fill="none"
              stroke="#7cb5ec"
              stroke-width="1"
            />
            <g
              class="highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-0"
              data-z-index="1"
              style="cursor: pointer;"
              transform="translate(300,360)"
            >
              <text
                data-z-index="1"
                style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; fill: #000000;"
                x="5"
                y="16"
              >
                <tspan
                  style="font-weight: bold;"
                >
                  acme
                </tspan>
                : 100.0 %
              </text>
            </g>
          </g>
          <g
            class="highcharts-legend highcharts-no-tooltip"
            data-z-index="7"
          >
            <rect
              class="highcharts-legend-box"
              fill="none"
              height="8"
              rx="0"
              ry="0"
              visibility="hidden"
              width="8"
              x="0"
              y="0"
            />
            <g
              data-z-index="1"
            >
              <g />
            </g>
          </g>
          <text
            class="highcharts-credits"
            data-z-index="8"
            style="cursor: pointer; color: rgb(153, 153, 153); font-size: 9px; fill: #999999;"
            text-anchor="end"
            x="590"
            y="395"
          >
            Highcharts.com
          </text>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

- I'm thinking of get the `g` element and click on it

  ```
  render(<BrowserRouter><DashboardPage store={store} /></BrowserRouter>);
          const company = screen.getAllByRole('g');
  ```

  but I got:

  ```
  TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "g"

      There are no accessible roles. But there might be some inaccessible roles. If you wish to access them, then set the `hidden` option to `true`. Learn more about this here: https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#byrole
  ```
- I'm trying to get element by class name:

  ```js
  it('Can handle handleOnUserClick on Chart', async () => {

      let initialState = {
          stats: {
              items: {
                  nUsersPerCompany: [
                      {
                          company: "demolitori", 
                          qty: 5, 
                          id: 16
                      }
                  ]
              }
          },
          setCompanyIdInUsersStore: () => {},
      };

      let store = mockStore(initialState);

      const { container } = render(<BrowserRouter><DashboardPage store={store} /></BrowserRouter>);
      // This console.log outputs the previous HTML code
      console.log(prettyDOM(container));
      const company = await container.getElementsByClassName("highcharts-label");
      console.log(company);
      fireEvent.click(company);

  });
  ```

  But with last `console.log(company)` I get an empty HTML collection:

  ```js
  HTMLCollection {}
  ```

  I tried also to remove the `async`/`await` mode without luck.

  I tried to use:

  ```js
  const {container} = render(<BrowserRouter><DashboardPage store={store} /></BrowserRouter>);
  console.log(prettyDOM(container))
  const path = container.getElementsByClassName("highcharts-color-0");
  console.log(prettyDOM(path[0]))
  fireEvent.click(path[0]);
  ```

  The test itself works, but coverage complain with missing the arrow function in click e

  ```js
  point: {
      events: {
          click: (e) => {
              props.setCompanyIdInUsersStore(e.target.point.idCompany);
              return navigate(PATH_USERS);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: `getByRole` is **not** the same thing as selecting an element name (although some elements' roles are the same as their names).

Comment: Which functions can I call, so?

Comment: Hi @sineverba, Could you add more info about the coverage problem? Also, you should also be able to get a point through reference to the `HighchartsReact` component.

Comment: @ppotaczek see edit #4, it must be clear. What do u mean with reference to the HighchartsReact component? I'm using Jest, so rendering the "real" page.

Comment: Would be easier if you add your `DashboardPage` component code, so we can try to simulate your component.

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto added new informations. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The coverage statistic is correct, as Highcharts render the elements using SVG and other components (path, rect etc.) that do not support click events simulation by DOM. If you replace click with mouseOver, your test coverage would hit 100%, as it is supported.
Highcharts team might be doing some custom implementation to achieve click handlers and we need to utilize that to solve your use case. @ppotaczek pointed out the correct approach.

Code modifications:

- Assume DashboardPage component accepts an optional prop, onAfterChartCreated.
- It passes that prop over to Chart component as value of callback.

```js
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import Chart from "./Chart";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

export const DashboardPage = (props) => {

    // previous code
    return (
        <Chart options={optionNUsersPerCompany} callback={props.onAfterChartCreated} />
    )
}

// follow up code

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DashboardPage);
```

- Chart component should be modified to:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';

export default React.memo(function Chart(props) {

    const [currentOptions, setCurrentOptions] = useState({});

    /**
     * Questo controllo serve a non re-draware per due volte di seguito i containers
     */
    if (JSON.stringify(props.options) !== JSON.stringify(currentOptions)) {
        setCurrentOptions(props.options);
    }

    return (
        <HighchartsReact
            highcharts={Highcharts}
            options={currentOptions}
            immutable={true}
            callback={props.callback}
        />
    );
});
```

callback is a prop on HighCharts react wrapper, that executes when chart is rendered and returns an instance of the chart. You could refer to their docs for more info or check out [How do i access highcharts api after component renders?](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react/issues/44)

Now we modify the test case for DashboardPage component as follows:

```
const afterChartCreatedCallback = (chart) => {
  // We can now trigger click on any data point using Highcharts API
  chart.series[0].data[0].firePointEvent('click');
}

render(<DashboardPage onAfterChartCreated={afterChartCreatedCallback} />);
```

So, we only use the callback in the test, to improve the coverage. This should increase your DashboardPage component coverage to 100%.

Comment: Thank you for your time and your effort! I tried your code but `chart` passed is undefined. I need to investigate better, but your answer seems interesting, very interesting.

You will get automatically the bounty, probably cannot test and confirm before expire. But, I wish to wish you a long trip on StackOverflow!

And you must have the bounty only for the time spent ;)

Comment: I used a static version of your code (hardcoded series data and commented out the actions) and coverage issue was reproducible. Coverage report indicated 100% coverage after I updated the test case, so not sure why the chart would be undefined for you. I hope you are able to debug it and thanks for your kind wishes.