# How to simulate click on React Highcharts Pie Chart arcs on React Testing Library?

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-highcharts

I want to test the click event on any arc of the highchart's Pie Chart,

I tried to take the reference from the data Label by something like

```
fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('93%'));`
```

and on main js file , I have added console :

```js
series: [{
  point: {
    events: {
      click(event) {
        console.log('2222222 clicked event')

      }
    }
  }
}]
```

but on console I got nothing

Comment: Hi @Anisha Pal Mohor, That's because SVG doesn't support click events simulation by DOM. Please check this similar thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72576640/how-can-i-simulate-a-click-on-highchart And a possible solution with `firePointEvent`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233681/programatically-fire-a-click-event-for-a-point-on-highchart-scatter-plot You can get a point through: `Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].points[1]`.